# "waver one's determination"

Tags: verbs

> 1. She never wavers in her determination to shoot for the moon
> 2. She never wavers her determination to shoot for the moon.

My question is whether waver can be used as a transitive verb that can modify something.

Comment: Have you looked up 'waver' in a dictionary?

Comment: I have looked up in a dictionary that suggets waver is used only as a intransitive verb, but I have seen this kind of usage. So I am not sure. @MichaelHarvey

Comment: I am an educated, widely-read, older native speaker, and I have never seen that usage, and if I did, would regard it as an error. Things or people waver, they are not "wavered".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you know english is such a widely used language that many people employed as a second language. That's maybe why I saw the incorrect usage.

Comment: It may just be a case of omitting the "in", though the meaning stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Waver" is an [intransitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waver).** "Wavers her determination" is wrong.